# Michelson interferometer finding $\frac{\Delta \nu}{\bar \nu}$?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, interference, interferometry

Let us say we send light with wavenumber $\bar \nu \pm \frac{\Delta \bar \nu}{2}$ through a Michelson Interferometer. Using the intensity at the center of the interference pattern $I(x)$ (where $x$ is the separation of the mirrors), how could we measure experimentally the value of the ratio:
$$\frac{\Delta \bar \nu}{\bar \nu}$$

I know you could just measure $\Delta \nu$ and $\bar \nu$ separately (using the modulating envelope and high frequency oscillations) but I think there must be an easier way. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

It is probably worth mentioning that the intensity distribution takes the form:
$$I(x)=\frac{I_0}{2}(1+\cos(\bar \nu \pi x)\cos(\Delta \bar \nu \pi x))$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that this is the best method but it is the only one I can think of.

1. Find a location of minium ($0$) visibility (which is easy to detect) [1].
2. Looking at the center of the intensity distribution, move one the mirrors to until you reach the next location of minium ($0$) visibility.
3. When moving the mirrors count the number  $n$ of minium is achieved at the center.
4. You then have the following:$$\frac{\Delta \bar \nu}{\bar \nu}=\frac{1}{n}$$
5. You could do the normal things, like repeating at different minium visibilities etc. to further improve accuracy.

**References**

[1] Shepherd, G.G. 2002. *Spectral Imaging of the Atmosphere*. Volume 82. London: Academic Press (p135)